# What is the maximum number of instance variables that a Java Class should have?

Tags: java, oop

Is it good OO design to have 20-25 instance variables in a JAVA class, with their getter/setters?
All variables are totally independent.
As I am using a class in HBase, which represents a column family, so that column family can have different number of columns for each row. So I have to put this much number of variables in that class.
I am very curious to know,
How many instance variables and methods should a JAVA class have ideally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, if your class represents data holder objects, then it is perfectly Ok to go with that. This design is common in java beans.

for example, If yo you have a class which represents an employee in a company, then it is quite usual, if an employee has 20-25 attributes.

But if you are messing so much instance variables with business methods, then down the line you will face difficulties, as you will not be able to get concentrated and focused business components.

To make it more better architecture-wise, you can consider Inheritance(sub-class) or composition(inner class)

Answer (score 7):

Trying to have good OO, it is good to look for the class to have a single responsibility.
So if you have so many unrelated variables, it sounds like the class is doing too much.

This would be a "code smell" and you should consider re-factoring into multiple classes.

Its great you are interested in good OO. I recommend reading up on Refactoring and Code Smells.

http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneResponsibilityRule would be relative here..

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object might apply as well.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't really matter as long as you are ensuring low [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). Assigning so many variables to a class might increase the chances of high coupling.

Also, it might be a sign of low [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29) in your class, as opposed to the ideal situation of high cohesion.

Answer (score 2):

At 20-25 instance variables you should be within the limit, however, I think that 20-25 might be too much. You could try and group these into different classes and reduce the amount of instance variables.

Usually having a lot of instance variables makes the class limited in scope, which is not ideal in a scenario where you would like to maintain the solution. Breaking it down (if done properly) should increase the re-usability of some of your classes.

Answer (score -1):

Java don't have any limitation on java instance variable that a class can have. As per you requirement you can have any number of instance variables.

Key point to remember is thay should be accessible only by getter and setter methods. A user should not be able to access them directly with instance variable's name.

Means Instance variable should be declared with private modifiers and must provide public methods to access and manipulate them.

Comment: Hey, JVM has a limitation